# What do the bands on the door mean?

Tags: blue-lacuna

In [Blue Lacuna](http://www.lacunastory.com/), I've found a door containing a series of buttons labeled with tiny pictograms of objects and creatures from around the island. Adorning the door at eye-level is a series of six colored bands directly on the wood. From left to right, the colors are red, yellow, black, white, blue, and green.

I'm not looking for the solution to this puzzle, yet, but I *am* curious whether I should be able to solve it already. Do the bands have something to do with how the door is opened? Is the information explaining how to decode the bands' meaning self-evident—in other words, will it be obvious to me when I'm ready to open this door, or should I be looking for the solution in more oblique corners of the game world?

Comment: So you're not confused, I removed the [tag:interactive-fiction] tag as per our policy of using genre tags only when asking questions *about* the genre. We prefer not to use them for question classification due to [issues discussed here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1857/underused-genre-tags/1858#1858).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit more exploring answered my own question. The bands quite obviously explain how to open the door—and armed with that knowledge, doing so was trivial.